# Calculating the Bounding Rectangle at an Angle of a Polygon

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry

I have the need to determine the bounding rectangle for a polygon at an arbitrary angle. This picture illustrates what I need to do:

[alt text http://kevlar.net/RotatedBoundingRectangle.png](http://kevlar.net/RotatedBoundingRectangle.png)

The pink rectangle is what I need to determine at various angles for simple 2d polygons.

Any solutions are much appreciated!

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answers, I got it working once I got the center points correct. You guys are awesome!

Comment: By "various angles" do you mean the bounding rectangle has to be at a certain angle, or the shape inside has to be at a certain angle?

Comment: You'll have to fix some angles here else there are multiple solutions.

Comment: The angle of the bounding rectangle is what varies. I've thought about rotating the polygon in the reverse direction, then fitting a rectangle around it, and rotating the points of the rectangle back, but I think I'm getting messed up by identifying the center points correctly.

Comment: Just rotate both about 0,0.  You don't need the center point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a bounding box with a certain angle, rotate the polygon the other way round by that angle. Then you can use the min/max x/y coordinates to get a simple bounding box and rotate that by the angle to get your final result.

From your comment it seems you have problems with getting the center point of the polygon. The center of a polygon should be the average of the coordinate sums of each point. So for points P1,...,PN, calculate:

```
xsum = p1.x + ... + pn.x;
ysum = p1.y + ... + pn.y;
xcenter = xsum / n;
ycenter = ysum / n;
```

To make this complete, I also add some formulas for the rotation involved. To rotate a point (x,y) around a center point (cx, cy), do the following:

```
// Translate center to (0,0)
xt = x - cx;
yt = y - cy;
// Rotate by angle alpha (make sure to convert alpha to radians if needed)
xr = xt * cos(alpha) - yt * sin(alpha);
yr = xt * sin(alpha) + yt * cos(alpha);
// Translate back to (cx, cy)
result.x = xr + cx;
result.y = yr + cx;
```

Comment: Beat me to the centre-point calculation. +1 for having the right answer.

Comment: For this algorithm, does it matter what point you rotate about?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if you just want to know the size of the bounding box, but it will help with the placement of the bounding box around the polygon.

Comment: Even for bounding box placement, it seems like as long as you rotate the box & shape back around the same point once you've placed it, it'll work.

Comment: I think your yr = yt * sin(alpha) + yt * cos(alpha);
is wrong, don't you want it to be:
yr = xt * sin(alpha) + yt * cos(alpha); ?

Comment: To make it work I had to rotate the rectangle using the centerx and y of the polygon, which is where I was going wrong. I was rotating the rectangle around its center rather than the original center point of the poly. Thanks!

Comment: Emmett, you're right about the rotation, this saves some calculations.

Answer (score 3):

To get the smallest rectangle you should get the right angle. This can acomplished by an algorithm used in collision detection: oriented bounding boxes.
The basic steps:

Get all vertices cordinates
Build a covariance matrix
Find the eigenvalues
Project all the vertices in the eigenvalue space
Find max and min in every eigenvalue space.

For more information just google OBB "colision detection"

Ps: If you just project all vertices and find maximum and minimum you're making AABB (axis aligned bounding box). Its easier and requires less computational effort, but doesn't guarantee the minimum box.

Answer (score 2):

I'm interpreting your question to mean "For a given 2D polygon, how do you calculate the position of a bounding rectangle for which the angle of orientation is predetermined?"

And I would do it by rotating the polygon against the angle of orientation, then use a simple search for its maximum and minimum points in the two cardinal directions using whatever search algorithm is appropriate for the structure the points of the polygon are stored in. (Simply put, you need to find the highest and lowest X values, and highest and lowest Y values.)

Then the minima and maxima define your rectangle.

You can do the same thing without rotating the polygon first, but your search for minimum and maximum points has to be more sophisticated.

Comment: This is correct. The bounding box should not be calculated for the polygon with 0 rotation and then rotating the bound. This might yield too big bbox. I'm assuming AABB (axis aligned).

Answer (score 1):

To get a rectangle with minimal area enclosing a polygon, you can use [a rotating calipers](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/maer.html) algorithm.

The key insight is that (unlike in your sample image, so I assume you don't actually require minimal area?), any such minimal rectangle is collinear with at least one edge of (the convex hull of) the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python implementation for the answer by @schnaader.
Given a pointset with coordinates x and y and the degree of the rectangle to bound those points, the function returns a point set with the four corners (and a repetition of the first corner).

```
def BoundingRectangleAnglePoints(x,y, alphadeg):
    #convert to radians and reverse direction    
    alpha = np.radians(alphadeg)
    
    #calculate center
    cx = np.mean(x)
    cy = np.mean(y)

    #Translate center to (0,0)
    xt = x - cx
    yt = y - cy

    #Rotate by angle alpha (make sure to convert alpha to radians if needed)
    xr = xt * np.cos(alpha) - yt * np.sin(alpha)
    yr = xt * np.sin(alpha) + yt * np.cos(alpha)

    #Find the min and max in rotated space
    minx_r = np.min(xr)
    miny_r = np.min(yr)
    maxx_r = np.max(xr)
    maxy_r = np.max(yr)
    #Set up  the minimum and maximum points of the bounding rectangle    
    xbound_r = np.asarray([minx_r, minx_r, maxx_r, maxx_r,minx_r])
    ybound_r = np.asarray([miny_r, maxy_r, maxy_r, miny_r,miny_r])
    
    #Rotate and Translate back to (cx, cy)
    xbound = (xbound_r * np.cos(-alpha) - ybound_r * np.sin(-alpha))+cx
    ybound = (xbound_r * np.sin(-alpha) + ybound_r * np.cos(-alpha))+cy
  
    return xbound, ybound
```